# Fetching relevant data with every comment / message using dynamodb

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm trying to design my first DynamoDB table. Some items will represent users data (profile image URL for example), some items will represent reviews of other users and so on. I am looking for an efficient way to fetch user data with every review. The query would fetch all / most recent 10 reviews of a certain user posted by others. The thing is I can duplicate reviewer's info on every review but somethings like image URL are mutable and may get changed frequently and it seems so inefficient to update user data in all these places as what if this user is active and posts so many reviews, comments, …. The other way I could think of is first query the reviews then do a batch read to get reviewer's data using userIds of every review but this would be very inefficient and costly as well.

I'm assuming this is a common issue as I can think of many use cases similar to this (Comments on a YouTube video or a post, followers of a twitter account, …) and in all these cases you would want to get the relevant user data (image URL & username for example). So, is there a better way I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the image URLs immutable ? You might be able to bake in a convention between components.

For example, if the review of ID 1 may have at most 1 image then that image will be at something like https://example.com/reviews/1/image.jpg

If they can have more than one image then you could use a json as an index (with a low cache-control) in that same URL and let the browser figure it out.

My point being here: denormalized mutable values are probably better of outside DynamoDB.

The other option is to smash all the data in one record. Like that you can use DynamoDB maps and list to map all images in a review. This may work as long as you query efficiently with the projection expression attribute and you write surgically. Otherwise your RCU/WCU are gonna be too high if you operate over the entire item all the time. This also depends on your use case being ok with the max size of a DynamoDB document.